# In ruby, how do I split a string into an array, using only the last occurrence of a word

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, parsing, split

I am creating an event, and I would like to be able to parse a single string and populate the model's attributes. As an example, I would like to do the following:

```
string = "Workout at the gym at 7pm on July 4th for 1 hour"
```

from this string, I would like to set the following variables:

```
title = Workout at the gym

date_time = 7pm on July 4th

duration = 1 hour
```

Comment: Do you have anything that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
/^(.*) at (\d{1,2}[a|p]m.*) for (.*)$/gm
```

In the replace, you would use:

```
title = $1\n\ndate_time = $2\n\nduration = $3
```

Working example: http://regexr.com?35i10

**Explanation**:

`^` means that we want to start at the beginning of the line

`(.*) at` means store everything until `at` in first variable.

`(\d{1,2}[a|p]m.*)` means a 1 or 2 digit number (`\d{1,2}`) followed by `a` OR `p` + `m` then another everything until...

`for` simple enough.

`(.*)$` means store everything until the end of the line.

`/gm` tells the regular expression to be Global and Multi-line

Answer (score 1):

If you are always going to use that format you can do:

```
re = string.match(/(?<title>.*) at (?<date_time>.*) for (?<duration>.*)/)
title, date_time, duration = re[:title], re[:date_time], re[:duration]
# ["Workout at the gym", "7pm on July 4th", "1 hour"]
```

Comment: looks good, what about throwing a `Hash#values_at` there?

Comment: I wasn't sure if `MatchData` necessarily acted like a `Hash`, and it looks like `values_at` here expects integers (`Array` style). I just added the second line for the asker's example: I probably wouldn't worry about re-assigning variables and would just use `re[:title]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Workout at the gym at 7pm on July 4th for 1 hour"
a = str.split(/at|for/).map(&:strip)
# => ["Workout", "the gym", "7pm on July 4th", "1 hour"]
duration,date_time,title = a.pop,a.pop,a.join(" ")
duration # => "1 hour"
date_time # => "7pm on July 4th"
title # => "Workout the gym"
```